# An infinite $\sigma$-algebra contains an infinite sequence of nonempty, disjoint sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to solve Exercise 3 a) given [here](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~astern/5051f12/hw1.pdf). The problem states:

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an infinite $\sigma$-algebra. Prove that
>   $\mathcal{M}$ contains an infinite sequence of nonempty, disjoint
>   sets. (Hint: if $\mathcal{M}$ contains an infinite sequence of
>   strictly nested sets, then we’re done, so assume that no such sequence
>   exists. Next, use this assumption to find a nonempty set in
>   $\mathcal{M}$ with no nonempty proper subsets in $\mathcal{M}$.
>   Finally, show that this can be done infinitely many times.)

Here's my idea: Let's say $\mathcal{M}$ is $\sigma$-algebra on the set $X$. If $\mathcal{M}$ does not contain an infinite sequence of strictly nested sets, then given any $A\in\mathcal{M}$, every strict chain starting with $A$ must terminate after finite time: i.e. $A\subsetneq E_{1}\subsetneq E_{2}\subsetneq … \subsetneq E_{k}$ and there is no set $X\neq B\in\mathcal{M}$ such that $E_{k}\subsetneq B$. But then the complement $E_k^{c}$ has no nonempty proper subsets in $\mathcal{M}$. But I am having trouble showing that the process can repeated infinitely many times.

I have been stuck with this for the whole day, and it is driving me crazy! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a hint:  can you show that $\mathcal{M}_1 := \{Y \cap E_k\ | Y \in \mathcal{M}\}$ is an infinite $\sigma$-algebra (and a subset of $\mathcal{M}$) with the same property?  Now repeat this process, obtaining $\mathcal{M}_n$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and finding a set $A_n$ disjoint from each previous set $A_i$ ($i<n$) at every step in the process.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{M}_1$ a $\sigma$-algebra though? It doesn't seem to contain $X$ itself. Or maybe it is a $\sigma$-algebra on another set?

Comment: It will be a $\sigma$-algebra on $E_k$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense :) Thank you! So I can see that $\mathcal{M}_1$ will be a $\sigma$-algebra on $E_k$. I have to think why it is infinite though. But once it is infinite, I can see that the process you describe will lead to infinitely many desired sets. +1!

Comment: If $Y\cap E_k=\emptyset$, then $Y\subseteq E_{k}^{c}$, but we know $E_{k}^{c}$ has no nonempty proper subsets. So $Y=\emptyset$. Does this show $\mathcal{M}_{1}$ infinite?

Comment: Basically.  Indeed, if $Y \neq X$, then $Y \cap E_k = Y$ or $Y = (Y\cap E_k) \cup E_k^c$.  So the map $Y \rightarrow Y \cap E_k$ is $2$ to $1$, and so its range must be infinite.

Comment: How does the map being 2 to 1 make the range infinite?

Answer (score 5):

I found a very interesting answer to the question using Hausdorff Maximal Principle [here](http://www.math.ttu.edu/~cmonico/teaching/fall12-5322/solns.pdf) in page 2.  Let me take a screenshot for now. I will come back and latexify this when I have the time. [image]